# Yii Ajax call to controller

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am very novice to Yii.There is a view file `absence.php` which submits data of a CActiveForm to a controller file `personal.php` inside of which there is a public function `createabsence()` which does everything: server validation, communication with the database and message handling.

```
<?php 
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',['id'=>'createAbsence','enableAJAXValidation'=>true]);
...
echo CHtml::submitButton('GO');
$this->endWidget();
?>
```

The above code is part of the view file; everything works fine. Form data passes to the controller and I am getting a response from the server. My problem is that the call to the controller is not an AJAX call and I have no idea how to convert this call to an AJAX call. Of course I know how to do that when dealing with something usual, however I do not know what I have to add/change in Yii.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use AjaxSubmitButton

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417868/yii2-activeform-ajax-submit-and-validation/34015264#34015264)

is related to ajaxsubmit.

Hope it helps you